# Получение элемента не находящегося в документе

Tags: javascript

В JS я написал функцию, которая создает слой div1 с ID=div1. После чего перестала работать ниже приведенная функция.

```
function div1()
{
var a = document.getElementById('div1');
a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+')';
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, в документе HTML теперь отсутствует div1, т.к. он пока ещё не создан. Как исправить эту функцию, что бы елемент брался не из документа и из функции в JS?

**UPD:**

```
var hide=true;
function movePic(word){
  _x=window.event.clientX;
  _y=window.event.clientY;
  _dx=5;
  left=false;right=false;
  if(_dx+_x+tool.clientWidth>document.body.clientWidth){_x=document.body.clientWidth-tool.clientWidth-_dx;left=true;}
  if(_dx+_y+tool.clientHeight>document.body.clientHeight){_y=document.body.clientHeight-tool.clientHeight-_dx;right=true;}
  if(left&&right)_y=document.body.clientHeight-tool.clientHeight-_dx*4;
  tool.style.left=_x;
  tool.style.top=_y+document.body.scrollTop;
  if(hide){
    tool.innerHTML=word;
    tool.style.visibility="visible";
    hide=false;
  }
}
function hidePic(){
  tool.style.visibility="hidden";
  tool.innerHTML="";
  tool.style.top=0;
  tool.style.left=0;
  hide=true;
}
function createElem() {
    var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
    var div1 = document.createElement('DIV');
    var divtwo = document.createElement('DIV');
    var div3 = document.createElement('DIV');
    var div4 = document.createElement('DIV');
    var div2 = document.createElement('DIV');
    div2.id = 'div2';
    div2.style.position='absolute';
    div2.style.backgroundColor='#00F';
    div2.style.width='120px';
    div2.style.height='60px';
    div2.style.textAlign='center';
    div2.style.lineHeight='60px';
    div2.onmousemove = function (){movePic('ToolTip')};
    div2.onmouseout = function (){hidePic()};
    div2.onclick = function (){div2()};
    div3.id = 'div3';
    div3.style.position='absolute';
    div3.style.backgroundColor='#FF0';
    div3.style.width='68px';
    div3.style.height='98px';
    div3.style.textAlign='center';
    div3.style.lineHeight='98px';
    div3.style.top='62px';
    div3.onmousemove = function (){movePic('ToolTip')};
    div3.onmouseout = function (){hidePic()};
    div3.onclick = function (){div3()};
    div4.id = 'div4';
    div4.style.position='absolute';
    div4.style.backgroundColor='#096';
    div4.style.width='49px';
    div4.style.height='98px';
    div4.style.textAlign='center';
    div4.style.lineHeight='98px';
    div4.style.top='62px';
    div4.style.left='70px';
    div4.onmousemove = function (){movePic('ToolTip')};
    div4.onmouseout = function (){hidePic()};
    div4.onclick = function (){div4()};
    divtwo.id = 'divtwo';
    divtwo.style.position='absolute';
    divtwo.style.width='120px';
    divtwo.style.height='160px';
    divtwo.style.left='160px';
    div1.id = 'div1';
    div1.style.position = 'absolute';
    div1.style.backgroundColor = '#F00' ;
    div1.style.width='120px';
    div1.style.height='160px';
    div1.style.textAlign = 'center';
    div1.style.lineHeight='160px';
    div1.onmousemove = function (){movePic('ToolTip')};
    div1.onmouseout = function (){hidePic()};
    div1.onclick = function (){div1()};
    var text1 = "DIV1";
    var text2 = "DIV2";
    var text3 = "DIV3";
    var text4 = "DIV4";
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(text1);
    var textNode2 = document.createTextNode(text2);
    var textNode3 = document.createTextNode(text3);
    var textNode4 = document.createTextNode(text4);
    div1.appendChild(textNode);
    div2.appendChild(textNode2);
    div3.appendChild(textNode3);
    div4.appendChild(textNode4);
    divtwo.appendChild(div2);
    divtwo.appendChild(div3);
    divtwo.appendChild(div4);
    parent.appendChild(div1);
    parent.appendChild(divtwo);
}
function getRand(min, max){
  return Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
}
function div1()
{
  var a = function (){createElem()}.getElementById('div1');
  a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+')';
}
function div2()
{
  var a = document.getElementById('div2');
  a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+')';
}
function div3()
{
  var a = document.getElementById('div3');
  a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+')';
}
function div4()
{
  var a = document.getElementById('div4');
  a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+','+getRand(0, 255)+')';
}
```

Comment: Функцию может приведете? или название ее хотя бы.

Comment: function createElem() эта функция создает элемент div1 c ID=div1

Comment: @Afimida, Добавьте в ваш вопрос весь алгоритм программы, который касается данной проблемы.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю. Точнее отредактирую.

Comment: Вот код. function div1() это мой эксперимент по вызову неудачный, хотя работает js не жалуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. div вызывается тольна при onclick по этому же диву. Так что сказать что он не создан - нельзя. Следовательно у вас какая - то другая ошибка.
2. Почитайте про [javascript bind](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/) в результате можно будет не делать

   var a = document.getElementById('div1');

и вместо этого писать просто this

3.

```
div1.style.position = 'absolute';
div1.style.backgroundColor = '#F00' ;
div1.style.width='120px';
div1.style.height='160px';
div1.style.textAlign = 'center';
div1.style.lineHeight='160px';
....
```

Ради бога, используйте вместо всего этого

```
div1.className = 'class-for-div1';
```

ну и соотвественно допишите в css

```
.class-for-div1 {
position: absolute;
background-color: #F00;
width: 120px;
height: 160px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 160px;
}
```

1. я не понял что и из-за чего не работает. Так как и выше коде есть функция div1 и в нижнем коде есть функция div1, причем они абсолютно разные
2. у вас функция и переменная имеют одинаковые названия, этого следует всячески избегать.
3. var a = function (){createElem()}.getElementById('div1'); -- как то странно это выглядит

ЗЫ: я ничего не запускал и не проверял, сказал "на глаз" возможно где-то и не прав

Comment: Я не знаю как вас отблагодарить но ваш комментарий оказался у меня в блокноте, помогло изменение названий функций. Спасибо большое вам!

Answer (score 2):

Используйте jQuery. Ваш код уменьшиться в несколько раз и все вопросы отпадут сами собой

Comment: Использовать jquery не зная основ js? Отличный совет.

Comment: Так что-то же знает, коль такие строки кода написал :) А вообще может и есть смысл в совместном изучении jquery и js, тем более, что первое является библиотекой второго!!! Я это к чему вообще - на jquery это действительно проще решается.

Если же все таки нужно на чистом js, то стоит задуматься о том, нужно ли динамически вообще создавать div-ы??? Может есть смысл создать их при формировании страницы и сделать их невидимыми, а затем производить над ними манипуляции. Тогда в этом случае лучше вместо свойства visibility использовать display

Comment: Полностью согласен с ikot. Все что вы делаете никуда не годится. И кстати, jquery  никого не освобождала от знания языка, более того, есть возможность научиться делать более высокого уровня вещи.